# Editable ComboBox behavior on arrow navigation in drop down

Tags: wpf, combobox

The default behavior for non-editable Combobox when you navigate through drop down list with Up and Down keys is, that the current item is highlighted but not selected. Only on Enter Key the Item gets selected.

If you set `IsEditable="True"` then the behavior is different. Currently selected item (and or Text input) changes by keyboard navigation in the drop down.

My problem with this is, that I'm filtering the items depending on text input. And when you select, you have one exact match and items count goes to one.

So it's not possible to select a correct item with a keyboard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inspired by blog post below (Thank you Diederik Krols) I'm finaly found a solution for my problem.

http://dotbay.blogspot.de/2009/04/building-filtered-combobox-for-wpf.html

It needed some extra work, but with a little bit Reflection and Binding suspendig, I have now combobox behavior like expected.

Here is my code

```
public enum FilterMode
{
    Contains,
    StartsWith
}

public class FilteredComboBoxBehavior : ManagedBehaviorBase<ComboBox>
{
    private ICollectionView currentView;
    private string currentFilter;
    private Binding textBinding;
    private TextBox textBox;

    private PropertyInfo HighlightedInfoPropetyInfo { get; set; }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty FilterModeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("FilterMode", typeof(FilterMode), typeof(FilteredComboBoxBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(default(FilterMode)));

    public FilterMode FilterMode
    {
        get
        {
            return (FilterMode)this.GetValue(FilterModeProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            this.SetValue(FilterModeProperty, value);
        }
    }


    public static readonly DependencyProperty OpenDropDownOnFocusProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("OpenDropDownOnFocus", typeof(bool), typeof(FilteredComboBoxBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(true));

    public bool OpenDropDownOnFocus
    {
        get
        {
            return (bool)this.GetValue(OpenDropDownOnFocusProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            this.SetValue(OpenDropDownOnFocusProperty, value);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnSetup()
    {
        base.OnSetup();
        this.AssociatedObject.KeyUp += this.AssociatedObjectOnKeyUp;
        this.AssociatedObject.IsKeyboardFocusWithinChanged += this.OnIsKeyboardFocusWithinChanged;
        this.textBox = this.AssociatedObject.FindChild<TextBox>();

        this.textBinding = BindingOperations.GetBinding(this.AssociatedObject, ComboBox.TextProperty);
        this.HighlightedInfoPropetyInfo = typeof(ComboBox).GetProperty(
            "HighlightedInfo",
            BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

        var pd = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, typeof(ComboBox));
        pd.AddValueChanged(this.AssociatedObject, this.OnItemsSourceChanged);
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();
        this.AssociatedObject.KeyUp -= this.AssociatedObjectOnKeyUp;
        if (this.currentView != null)
        {
            // ReSharper disable once DelegateSubtraction
            this.currentView.Filter -= this.TextInputFilter;
        }

        BindingOperations.ClearAllBindings(this);
    }


    private void OnItemsSourceChanged(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        this.currentFilter = this.AssociatedObject.Text;
        if (this.currentView != null)
        {
            // ReSharper disable once DelegateSubtraction
            this.currentView.Filter -= this.TextInputFilter;
        }

        if (this.AssociatedObject.ItemsSource != null)
        {
            this.currentView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.AssociatedObject.ItemsSource);
            this.currentView.Filter += this.TextInputFilter;
        }

        this.Refresh();
    }

    private void OnIsKeyboardFocusWithinChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
    {
        if (this.AssociatedObject.IsKeyboardFocusWithin)
        {
            this.AssociatedObject.IsDropDownOpen = this.AssociatedObject.IsDropDownOpen || this.OpenDropDownOnFocus;
        }
        else
        {
            this.AssociatedObject.IsDropDownOpen = false;
            this.currentFilter = this.AssociatedObject.Text;
            this.Refresh();
        }
    }

    private void AssociatedObjectOnKeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs keyEventArgs)
    {
        if (!this.IsTextManipulationKey(keyEventArgs)
            || (Keyboard.Modifiers.HasAnyFlag() && Keyboard.Modifiers != ModifierKeys.Shift)
            )
        {
            return;
        }

        if (this.currentFilter != this.AssociatedObject.Text)
        {
            this.currentFilter = this.AssociatedObject.Text;
            this.Refresh();
        }
    }

    private bool TextInputFilter(object obj)
    {
        var stringValue = obj as string;
        if (obj != null && !(obj is string))
        {
            var path = (string)this.GetValue(TextSearch.TextPathProperty);
            if (path != null)
            {
                stringValue = obj.GetType().GetProperty(path).GetValue(obj) as string;
            }
        }

        if (stringValue == null)
            return false;


        switch (this.FilterMode)
        {
            case FilterMode.Contains:
                return stringValue.IndexOf(this.currentFilter, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0;
            case FilterMode.StartsWith:
                return stringValue.StartsWith(this.currentFilter, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        }
    }

    private bool IsTextManipulationKey(KeyEventArgs keyEventArgs)
    {
        return keyEventArgs.Key == Key.Back 
            || keyEventArgs.Key == Key.Space 
            || (keyEventArgs.Key >= Key.D0 && keyEventArgs.Key <= Key.Z)
            || (Keyboard.IsKeyToggled(Key.NumLock) && keyEventArgs.Key >= Key.NumPad0 && keyEventArgs.Key <= Key.NumPad9)
            || (keyEventArgs.Key >= Key.Multiply && keyEventArgs.Key <= Key.Divide)
            || (keyEventArgs.Key >= Key.Oem1 && keyEventArgs.Key <= Key.OemBackslash);

    }

    private void Refresh()
    {
        if (this.currentView != null)
        {
            var tempCurrentFilter = this.AssociatedObject.Text;
            using (new SuspendBinding(this.textBinding, this.AssociatedObject, ComboBox.TextProperty))
            {
                this.currentView.Refresh();
                //reset internal highlighted info
                this.HighlightedInfoPropetyInfo.SetValue(this.AssociatedObject, null);
                this.AssociatedObject.SelectedIndex = -1;
                this.AssociatedObject.Text = tempCurrentFilter;

            }

            if (this.textBox != null && tempCurrentFilter != null)
            {
                this.textBox.SelectionStart = tempCurrentFilter.Length;
                this.textBox.SelectionLength = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Temporarely suspend binding on dependency property
/// </summary>
public class SuspendBinding : IDisposable
{
    private readonly Binding bindingToSuspend;

    private readonly DependencyObject target;

    private readonly DependencyProperty property;

    public SuspendBinding(Binding bindingToSuspend, DependencyObject target, DependencyProperty property)
    {
        this.bindingToSuspend = bindingToSuspend;
        this.target = target;
        this.property = property;
        BindingOperations.ClearBinding(target, property);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(this.target, this.property, this.bindingToSuspend);
    }
}


public abstract class ManagedBehaviorBase<T> : Behavior<T> where T : FrameworkElement
{
    private bool isSetup;
    private bool isHookedUp;
    private WeakReference weakTarget;

    protected virtual void OnSetup() { }
    protected virtual void OnCleanup() { }
    protected override void OnChanged()
    {
        var target = this.AssociatedObject;
        if (target != null)
        {
            this.HookupBehavior(target);
        }
        else
        {
            this.UnHookupBehavior();
        }
    }

    private void OnTargetLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) { this.SetupBehavior(); }

    private void OnTargetUnloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) { this.CleanupBehavior(); }

    private void HookupBehavior(T target)
    {
        if (this.isHookedUp) return;
        this.weakTarget = new WeakReference(target);
        this.isHookedUp = true;
        target.Unloaded += this.OnTargetUnloaded;
        target.Loaded += this.OnTargetLoaded;
        if (target.IsLoaded)
        {
            this.SetupBehavior();
        }
    }

    private void UnHookupBehavior()
    {
        if (!this.isHookedUp) return;
        this.isHookedUp = false;
        var target = this.AssociatedObject ?? (T)this.weakTarget.Target;
        if (target != null)
        {
            target.Unloaded -= this.OnTargetUnloaded;
            target.Loaded -= this.OnTargetLoaded;
        }
        this.CleanupBehavior();
    }

    private void SetupBehavior()
    {
        if (this.isSetup) return;
        this.isSetup = true;
        this.OnSetup();
    }

    private void CleanupBehavior()
    {
        if (!this.isSetup) return;
        this.isSetup = false;
        this.OnCleanup();
    }
}
```

XAML

```
<ComboBox IsEditable="True"
      Text="{Binding Path=ZipCode, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"
      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=PostalCodes}"
      IsTextSearchEnabled="False" 
      behaviors:AttachedMaxLength.ChildTextBoxMaxLength="{Binding Path=ZipCodeMaxLength}">
<i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <behaviors:FilteredComboBoxBehavior FilterMode="StartsWith"/>
</i:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

Comment: I have the same problem but I want to keep the behaviour of `IsEditable=false` when `IsEditable=true`. I want to navigate with arrow keys when IsEditable is true...

Comment: where should i get `HasAnyFlag` method?

Comment: @aquaprogit it is an extension method that looks like this
```c#
public static bool HasAnyFlag(this Enum value, params Enum[] flags)
    {
      foreach (Enum flag in flags)
      {
        if (value.HasFlag(flag))
          return true;
      }
      return false;
    }
```

Comment: @aquaprogit but it returns always `false` here in my example, so you can ignore/remove it